# Условие вывода массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы, вывод

В общем, есть массив с которого я вывожу данные на страницу. Для первого выведеного элемента из массива, мне нужно сделать блок 'div' "Активным". Я попытался это сделать так, но выводит ошибку: 'Getting unknown property: common\models\references\SQuizQuestion::0'

```
<?php foreach ($Questions as $Quest) { ?>

                    <?php if ($Quest[0]) { ?>
                        <div id="<?=$Quest['id_rec']?>" class="panel__item active">

                            <div class="text_question" align="center">
                                <?= $Quest->text_quest; ?>
                            </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

                            <div class="answer">
                                <?php foreach ($Quest->squizqa as $Answer) { ?>
                                    <p>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="<?=$Answer['id_rec']?>"> <?= $Answer->text_answer ?>
                                    </p>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

                        </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <div id="<?=$Quest['id_rec']?>" class="panel__item">

                                <div class="text_question" align="center">
                                    <?= $Quest->text_quest; ?>
                                </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->

                                <div class="answer">
                                    <?php foreach ($Quest->squizqa as $Answer) { ?>
                                        <p>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="<?=$Answer['id_rec']?>"> <?= $Answer->text_answer ?>
                                        </p>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->

                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>
```

Как правильно задать следующее условие:

```
Если ("Первый элемент массива"), то выводим
<div class="panel__item active">

иначе

<div class="panel__item">
```

Или это можно сделать еще каким то способом более адекватным, что бы такой участок кода не копировать?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки. Если это ошибка 500, то ищите текст ошибки в логах веб-сервера

Comment: участок и не надо копировать. вам внутри `class="bla bla bla"` надо ставить что-то вроде `<?= $idx == 0 ? "active" : "" ?>`

Comment: не понимаю людей, не использующих шаблонизаторы

Comment: @teran а конкретно как правильно добавить условие что бы именно первый блок 'div' был активным? а то "что-то вроде" я не совсем понимаю что и как на php определить является ли элемент массива первым) Вот и спрашиваю что и как.

Comment: @Sanvirtus вам дали уже ответ аналогичный , там вместо `$idx` используется флаг `$first`. И тут не определяется первый элемент или нет, а считаются итерации цикла вывода. Тем не менее рекомендую вам познакомится с такими шаблонизаторами как Smarty или Twig, это значительно упростит вашу жизнь

Comment: @teran  я работаю с yii2 сейчас так что мне пока что хватает с чем разбираться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$first = true;

foreach ($Questions as $Quest) : ?>
<div id="<?=$Quest['id_rec']?>" class="panel__item <?=($first) ? 'active' : ''?>">
    <div class="text_question" align="center">
        <?= $Quest->text_quest; ?>
    </div> <!-- <div class="text_question"> -->
    <div class="answer">
        <?php foreach ($Quest->squizqa as $Answer) { ?>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="<?=$Answer['id_rec']?>"> <?= $Answer->text_answer ?>
            </p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div> <!-- <div class="answer"> -->
</div>
<?php 
$first = false;
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: В таком случае все блоки активные

Comment: @Sanvirtus да признайтесь, что в конце `$first = false` забыли скопировать :)

Comment: не может быть, проверьте написание

Comment: @teran да, не заметил xD

Comment: спасибо огромное) помогло)